# PHP : Custom pagination in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I use this code for my custom paging :

```
global $wpdb, $table_prefix, $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();
$umail = $current_user->user_email;
$paged = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM {$table_prefix}comments WHERE comment_author_email = '$umail'");

$page = isset($_GET['page']) ? (int) $_GET['page'] : 1;
$pages = COUNT($paged);
$pages = ceil($pages / 2);

$querystring = "";
foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
    if ($key != "page") $querystring .= "$key=$value&amp;";
}

// Pagination
for ($i = 1; $i <= $pages; $i++) {
    echo "<a " . ($i == $page ? "class=\"selected\" " : "");
    echo "href=\"?{$querystring}page=$i";
    echo "\">$i</a> ";
}
```

This code paginate my comments look like this : 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11

How can change code to get paginate look like this: 1 2 3 ... 11

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What will be displayed if current page is 7: 1 2 3 ... 7 8 ... 11 or another?

Comment: Yep,most be 1 2 3 ... 7 8 ... 11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following loop:

```
$page           = 8;//current page
$pages          = 15;//count of all pages

$batch_middle   = 5;//the approximate number of pages in the middle links to display. Current page will be in the middle
$batch_lr       = 1;//number of pages in the left and right links
for($i = 1; $i <= $pages;$i++)  
{  
    //display first links
    if ($i <= $batch_lr) 
    {
        echo $i . ' '; 
        continue;
    }

    //display last links
    if ($i > $pages-$batch_lr) 
    {
        echo $i . ' '; 
        continue;
   }

    //display middle links
    if ($i>=($page-floor($batch_middle/2)) && $i<=($page+floor($batch_middle/2))) 
    {
        echo $i . ' '; 
        continue;
    }

    //placeholder
    echo ' ... ';

    //move the pointer
    $i = ($i < $page) ? ($page-floor($batch_middle/2)-1) : ($pages-$batch_lr) ;
}
//output example 1: 1 2 ... 14 15
//output example 2: 1 2 ... 7 8 9 ... 14 15
//output example 3: 1 2 3 4 5 ... 14 15
//output example 4: 1  ... 6 7 8 9 10 ... 15
```

Replace `$page` and `$pages` with your logic with getting a current page and count of total pages.
Replace the `$batch_middle` and `$batch_lr` to configure a number of links in the first, second and third batches of the links

Comment: Nice work, For last one, how can change to this method? `1 … 3 4 5 6 7 … 15`

Comment: Witch line must be edit for get result like top? I change $batch but no chance.